# Почему тут не ставится запятая перед "что"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Правдин прерывает сестру, говоря что гость устал с дороги и все
> расходятся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правилам здесь должна быть запятая. В этой фразе *что* вводит придаточную часть, зависимую от деепричастия в составе главной.

Согласно "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §115. (...) Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; если же придаточная часть стоит перед главной частью или после нее, то отделяется от нее запятой.

Соответственно, придаточная часть должна обособляться.

Кроме того, она должна обособляться с двух сторон, поскольку *и все расходятся* к ней не относится. Более того, *и все расходятся* — это вторая часть сложносочиненного предложения. Она и сама должна быть отделена запятой:

> §112. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится запятая.

Две запятые подряд не ставятся, оставляем одну. Получаем:

*Правдин прерывает сестру, говоря, **что гость устал с дороги**, и все расходятся.*

Вряд ли это опечатка — пропустить две запятые в одной фразе — полагаю, что автор краткого содержания допустил ошибку.

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно потому, что с деепричастия "говоря" начинается деепричастный оборот, который, кстати говоря, по-моему, должен ещё и со второй стороны выделяться запятой: ", говоря что гость устал с дороги, ". Но это не точно. Что-то связанное с частью речи, которой является "что" в данном случае. Наверное, слово "что" не всегда следует за запятой, а только в определённых случаях. Возможно, что надо ставить запятую в тех случаях, когда "что" отделяет одну часть составного предложения от другой или начинает какое-нибудь обособленное дополнение или определение, а в данном случае это деепричастный оборот (который, по-моему, сам по себе является обособленным дополением или вроде того), а не две части составного предложения. Какого-нибудь сложносочинённого или сложноподчинённого. Возможен такой вариант, что если слово "что" является предлогом, а не союзом, то перед ним не ставится запятая.